# Load html from js with ajax

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I'm having Problems with my AJAX call. I want to append html to an existing div:

```
var teaser = $(this);
var url = "http://..."

ajaxHandler.send({
  url: "//www...."
  dataFilter: function (data, type) {
    teaser.append($(data))
  }
});
```

The problem ist, that the URL (var url) I am sending gives a JS response like this:

```
document.open();
document.writeln('<div id=\"mydiv\" style=\"width:190px; height:160px\">');
document.writeln('   <img src=\"http:\/\/www.abc.gif\" width=\"190\" height=\"160\" alt=\"\" border=\"0\">');
document.writeln('<\/div>');
document.close();
```

I get the following error:

*Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: document.open();*

I'm using jQuery 2.x

Answer (score 2):

with an `ajax` request you are always getting the whole content of your request-url back (which probably also contains javascript) just like your server sends it. it doesn't execute javascript code - it just reads the sourcecode like it is returned.

why not just put pure html into your file:

```
<div id="mydiv" style="">
    <img src="http://www.example.com/my.gif">
</div>
```

then you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get a script from server and then execute it, you should use jquery [getScript](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/).

you can also use [load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) function like this:

```
$('#ad-container').load('script/location/on_server.php');
```

and return something like this from server(i.g make php to generate this code):

```
    <div id="mydiv" style="width:190px; height:160px">
        <img src="http://www.abc.gif" width="190" height="160" alt="" border="0">
    </div>
```

Comment: because some images (adserver stuff) should only be loaded if the user clicks on a certain button - unfortunatly

Comment: what is the problem with that?
you can do: `$('#that-button').click(function(){
$('#ad-container').load('script/location/on_server.php');
});`

Comment: OMG! i misunderstood your question. didn't i? can you control your server response or not? can you change the way server sends you information?

Comment: I guess so. No, I cannot control the sever response or change the way the server sends the information.